# I want multiple long text field to be displayed when a checkbox is checked on a visual force page?

Tags: visualforce, javascript

**Javascript:**

```
function inputDisplay(myCheck,inputId){
    if(myCheck.checked){
        document.getElementById(inputId).style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        document.getElementById(inputId).style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

**Apex:**

```
<tr>
    <td><b> Header Text </b></td>
    <td><apex:inputCheckbox value="{!Checkbox Value}" onchange="inputDisplay(this,'{!$Component.myInputId}')"/></td> 
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><apex:inputText id="myInputId" Value="{!long text Value}" required="true" styleclass="countable1"/></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: add more details to get proper help from community

Answer (score 2):

When you specify an `id` attribute for any `Visualforce` tag, it does not get literally added, but rather ends up looking something like:

```
<input id="thePage:theTable:0:theInput" ...>
```

You need to use an `ends with` (`$=`) selector, class name, or any of a variety of other strategies to select `Visualforce` tags.

```
document.querySelector('[id$="' + inputId + '"]').style.display = 'block';
```

I prefer using a `class` selector, which is also more fitting for your use case:

```
<apex:inputField styleClass="myTextArea" ... />
document.getElementsByClassName('myTextArea').forEach(function (element) {
    element.style.display = 'block';
});
```

See also: [Best Practices for Accessing Component IDs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_best_practices_accessing_id.htm)

You should also learn how to use the developer tools in your browser of choice. There should be a javascript console that would surface an error telling you your `document.getElementById` call failed to retrieve a DOM element.